# Action on Google with AWS LAMBDA in python

Tags: python, lambda, aws-api-gateway, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I wrote AWS Lambda function in python for my smart home Alexa skill. I wanted to implement the actions on google on the same lambda. Is there any option to implement the same? I'm not much comfortable using Node JS. Also don't want to change the technology stack of lambda. As it's a Live skill. Can anyone suggest to me what to do? Any step by step guide or tutorial will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [smart home action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/create) in any programming language. The platform incorporates JSON requests to your webhook and expects JSON responses. You can look at the [platform reference guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/sync) for the expected requests and responses.

In the Actions Console, after creating your Smart Home Action, you can specify [the URL for your webhook](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/process-intents).

Comment: Hey Thanks for responding, I have already gone through the [smart home action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/process-intents#sync-request) articles. But not able to get about the appropriate changes I do need to make in my lambda function. FYI, my lambda skill is already up and running nicely with Amazon Alexa. Do I need to make changes in `action_schema.json` to get it working with actions on google?  Also, I tried to test it with  [auth 2.0 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/?code=ANIGrrDANFqbmJwMdZhn&scope=profile). A brief info could help.